# Laravel - Best way to store user and his/her dynamically created relations on submit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, submit, one-to-many

Which way should I store User Relations which are made "Dynamically"?

By that i mean. I have People table with record of `husband` for example now husband can add as relation to him (hasMany) his wife and children. Now I have setup the model and it works

**Model**

This relations are in same table as data is same for them I only need to know if they belong to `husband`

```
public function children(){
   return $this->hasMany( get_class($this) ,'people_id','id');        
}
public function parent(){     
   return $this->belongsTo( get_class($this) , 'people_id','id');
}
```

Now when i go to form and add a person `husband` there. I would have an option to dynamically add his `children()` (his wife, his children, his grandma...) and submit once its done.

Now i have tought about saving these `children` to Session first (put them in array) and on submit to post it to controller. Is this a good way or should i do it some other way?

(I hope i explained this well, if not i will try to explain it better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it like this i dont know if this way is ok but it works for me. Also to add i have just used name for the DB data as i wanted to get this to work.

*Store parent and his/her children (if any) in DB from Session*

```
public function store(AdminCreatePersonRequest $request) 
{

 $data = $request->all();

 $parent =  new Person;

 $parent->name = $data['name'];

 $parent->save();

 $children = $request->session()->pull('children');


 if ($children != null) {

    foreach($children as $childData){

        $child = new Person(['name' => $childData['child-name']]);
        $parent->children()->save($child);

    }
 }

return redirect('dashboard')->with('success', ['The user was successfully created']);

}
```

**AJAX**

*Add child to session*

```
public function add(AdminCreatePersonChildRequest $request) 
{
    $temp = $request->session()->get('children',[]); 

    $data = $request->all(); 

    unset($data['_token']); 

    array_push($temp,$data); 

    end($temp); 

    $key = key($temp); 

    $data += ['id' => $key]; 

    $request->session()->put('children', $temp); 

    return $data;
}
```

*Remove child from session*

```
 public function delete(Request $request, $id) {

        $temp = $request->session()->pull('children');
        unset($temp[$id]);
        $request->session()->put('children', $temp);

        return 1;

 }
```

*Load children from Session on view create (if any)*

```
public function load(Request $request) //get children from session (if exists)
{
    $data = $request->session()->get('children');
    if($data != null){
        return $data;
    }

    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

*Clear all children from session*

```
public function clear(Request $request) //remove children from session
{
   $request->session()->forget('children');

   return 1;
}
```

And with data form controller you update your view (in my case add `<li>` to `<ul>` element)